# How can I define default options for xorg graphics devices

Tags: linux, usb, graphics-card, xorg, udev

I have a laptop and an external USB graphics card. I have a `xorg.conf.d` snippet like this:

```
Section "Device"
  Identifier  "USB3"
  Driver      "modesetting"
  Option      "kmsdev" "/dev/dri/card1"
  Option       "PageFlip" "off"
EndSection
```

That works fine but only if the USB adapter is plugged in and recognized **before** the X server starts. X *will* detect the adapter when I hotplug it, but it will *not* apply the option `"PageFlip" "off"`. I have found documentation on how to [configure **input** device options](https://wiki.kubuntu.org/X/InputConfiguration) using `udev`, because obviously hotplugging input devices is more common than hotplugging graphics output devices.

Is there a way to configure a X `Device` that is hotplugged, either through `udev` or any kind of `xorg.conf.d` snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it was [proposed some time ago](https://xorg-devel.x.narkive.com/BfYyN2Qi/patch-config-udev-get-driver-suggestions-from-udev) but not accepted. The preferred solution to implement a VideoClass directive similar to InputClass has apparently never been done.